# SSIS Package Lookup not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I've a SSIS package where I would like to validate the `productCode` by making sure that it exists on destination database.

The way I've done is setup the Lookup Transformation and mapped source `productCode` with destination `productCode`. The destination `productCode` is retrieved by simple sql query.

However, every time I run the package the data doesn't get matched even though all `productcode` on csv file exists on destination table.

Am I using Lookup for wrong purpose?

The back end is Oracle DB. Also noticed that Lookup Component has exclamation mark with "Cannot retrieve the column page info from OLEDB provider".

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using `Full Cache Mode` in Lookup? I suspect that there might be `case sensitive` issues while matching the data. Either use `No Cache` or convert your input and the Oracle column to `lower or upper case`

Comment: Unlike a SQL join, Full Cache Mode will also not match if there are differences in trailing spaces.

Comment: I did RTRIM(UPPER(value)). For some reason it only matches the last record on file. I can see CRLF on all records but not last. COuld this be issue, if so how do I fix this.

Comment: As soon as I hit ENTER on last record which inserts CRLF. The LOOKUP doesn't match completely. CODEPAGE is 1252

Comment: Instead of LOOKUP why don't you use LEFT OUTER JOIN at the source query, it would be easier.

Comment: Hmm, how would that help if my requirement is to validate if product code is valid?